# Mail server behind Vyatta NAT with two WAN connections

Tags: routing, nat, vyatta

I have a Vyatta router with eth0 and eth1 on the same network segment ex. 99.99.99.0/24 where eth0 is .1 and eth1 is .2 and this is the wan network segment.

The traffic to the default gateway is through eth0.

Also there is an internal network ex. 1.1.1.0/24 with an email server on it .10.

What I want to achieve is all the internal traffic to be NAT-ed through eth0 except the mail traffic wHich I want to be through eth1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using Policy Based Routing (PBR).

But the fact you have 2 interfaces in the same network makes it difficult because you cannot choose witch interface the router will use to reach the next-hop and you can only specify it by IP (and not interface) in Vyatta PBR.

Why do you have both interface in the same LAN? It will cause many issues.

At least you could have one interface with IP in the 99.99.99.0/24 network and the other interface with IP in the 1.1.1.0/24.

Even if both are actually in the same network segment that would dramatically simplify the configuration...

**Edit :**

OK misunderstood where the 1.1.1.0/24 was placed.
The question remains... why?

This is not a good setup. Whatever the reason behind having 2 interfaces in the same IP network is, there should be a better solution.

In this configuration I don't see how to achieve what you want.

If you set another network between Vyatta eth1 and your gateway (a /30 for example) , then you can do it.

**Edit 2 following last comment :**

If you want to have your email server NATed to a different IP, to avoid blacklisting, then it's easy to do without bothering with 2 interfaces.
You don't even have to set the IP on the interface, it works with nat rules only.

1 - remove the configuration on eth1

2 - set your nat source rule like:

> rule 10 {
>
> ```
>  description "Mail server"
>  outbound-interface eth0
>  source
>      address 1.1.1.10/32
>  translation {
>      address 99.99.99.2
>  }
> ```
>
> rule 20 {
>
> ```
>  description "all other machines"
>  outbound-interface eth0
>  source
>      address 1.1.1.0/24
>  translation {
>      address 99.99.99.1
>  }
> ```

You can even specify only TCP port 25 in rule 10 (add "protocol tcp" and "source port 25")

Of course, the key point here is to have the NAT rule for the mail server having a lower number than the more generic network NAT.

3 - Set a nat destination rule like:

> rule 10 {
>
> ```
>  description "Mail server"
>  inboud-interface eth0
>  destination
>      address 99.99.99.2
>      port 25  #add 80/443/110/143 if needed
>  protocol tcp
>  translation {
>      address 1.1.1.10
> ```

Comment: Yeah, a drawing of your network layout might help a lot to understand that very uncommon network layout...

Comment: Here is the picture with the layout: [network](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54030481/network.png)

Comment: see my edit. also you can edit the initial question to provide more details, and on Stack Exchange it's better to add relevant content in the post rather to link it to avoid broken link, so the content remains available to help futur users.

Comment: Both 99... ips are on my isp network. The reason is if the 1.1.1.0 network has a virus (was a conficker in my case on an old xp sp2 box, now retired)  and your main IP (99.99.99.1) get blacklisted then the mail server cannot send mail anymore. So I tried this solution.
I'll try a differnet approach. Thank you!

Comment: see my last edit for how to do this.

Comment: Thank you JFL for all your help. I'll try this and I'll post the results.

Comment: I haven't made the changes yet. I still have a question. I need to configure the eth0 interface with the 99.99.99.2 IP, don't I? (and remove the configuration for eth1).

Comment: No it's not needed to add the IP .2 on the interface, if you do so the router could originate some traffic from it so it's no recommended for your case.

Comment: I tried to commit the source nat rule. The answer is as follows:

`[ nat source ]`
`Warning: IP address 99.99.99.2 does not exist on the system!`

Comment: Yes that's only a warning and doesn't prevent the commit to be applied. It should work.